# SendKey если while(true)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Подскажите пожалуйста,как можно сделать эмуляцию нажатия клавиши раз в Х секунд пока условие верно?

```
if (e == Keys.RControlKey)
                {
                    if (!IsAfk)
                    {
                        IsAfk = true;
                        Update(); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IsAfk = false;
                       Update();
                    } 
                }
   private void Update()
        {
while (IsAfk)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("W");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                if (!IsAfk)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
}
```

Вот что-то такое у меня.Клавиша W отправляется,но не могу остановить.Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?На С# сижу 3й день,пытаюсь освоить)

P.S пытаюсь получить что-то формата:
Я нажимаю на **RCtrl** у меня начинает выполняться цикл с нажатием кнопки **W** раз в 3 секунды.Снова нажимаю на **RCtrl** и если цикл был запущен,его должно остановить.Если не был запущен,то запускаем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код синхронный. Пока выполняется цикл, ничто другое выполняться не может. Попробуйте запустить его в отдельной задаче.

```csharp
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

```csharp
if (e == Keys.RControlKey)
{
    if (!IsAfk)
    {
        IsAfk = true;
        Task.Run(() => Update()); 
    }
    else
    {
        IsAfk = false;
    } 
}
```

Задача не остановится мгновенно, а только через 3 секнуды, и есть вероятность повторного запуска, если часто нажимать **Ctrl**, поэтому я добавил дополнительную защиту в виде переменной `isRunning`.

```csharp
private bool isRunning;

private void Update()
{
    if (isRunning) return;
    isRunning = true;
    while (IsAfk)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("W");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        if (!IsAfk)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Обратите нимание, что после нажатия `Crtl`, если вы не успеете его очень быстро отпустить, то первое нажатие **W** сработает как комбинация горячих клавиш **Ctrl+W**.

Если подойти к делу серьезно, то такое лучше реализовать с помощью `async/await` и `CancellationToken`, но это сделает пример очень далеким от вашего кода, поэтому я написал более простой и понятный пример, способный решить вашу задачу.